# Makefile made by qmake only works on my pc

Tags: qt, makefile, qmake

For a university project we made an OpenGL application which uses Qt for the GUI. When I use `qmake -spec macx-g++ project.pro` I can make a `Makefile`, and if I then do `make` it correctly makes the application. However, when I then send the complete folder to the other person in the project and he does `make` he gets the error

```
Makefile:209: warning: overriding commands for target `moc_window.cpp'
Makefile:203: warning: ignoring old commands for target `moc_window.cpp'
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/mkspecs/default/qmake.conf', needed by `Makefile'.  Stop.
```

However, when in the same folder he does `qmake; make` it does work correctly. The problem is that when handing the code in we don't know if the professor has qmake available, so we would like it to work by only using `make`. Are we missing something that should be addded to have the `Makefile` made with `qmake` work, without having to do `qmake` again? Our `.pro` file is below.

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = smoke

QT = core gui opengl

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES += \
    fluids.cpp \
    simulation.cpp \
    visualization.cpp \
    window.cpp \
    myglwidget.cpp \
    vector.cpp \
    grid.cpp \
    scalar.cpp

HEADERS += \
    window.h \
    myglwidget.h \
    simulation.h \
    vector.h \
    grid.h \
    visualization.h \
    scalar.h

INCLUDEPATH += fftw-2.1.5/include /usr/local/include include
LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/fftw-2.1.5/lib" -lrfftw -lfftw -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -stdlib=libc++

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11


FORMS += \
    window.ui
```

Comment: *we don't know if the professor has qmake available* if you require Qt to compile your project, then you do have `qmake` available. Do not ever ship `Makefile`s around (or any other build artifact).

Comment: `make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib64/qt3.3/mkspecs/default/qmake.conf', needed by 'Makefile'. ` would indicate to me that qmake builds the makefile dependent on the user's Qt configuration. So in order to build a Qt project, you'll need Qt (And, by default, qmake).

Comment: Ah then I don't understand the function of having `qmake` make a `Makefile`, why does `qmake` not build the application direclty? I was hoping that with the Makefile someone else could build it using only `make` as well

Comment: Writing a `qmake` file means you as Qt user don't have to go through the trouble of writing a Makefile by hand (detecting the Qt dir, handling different compilers, etc). `qmake` producing a Makefile means the Qt developers didn't have to re-implement the whole of `make`. Everybody saves time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build directory is not portable. It is only ever meant to work on the system where you executed qmake, and for the particular Qt install that you ran qmake from. Recall that each Qt install has its own qmake, so e.g. if you have three Qt versions, each provides its own qmake that you *must* use to build a project using that version.

The project you ship should contain the `.pro` file, the sources, and whatever else the build calls for, like icon files, resources, etc.

The recipient, to build it, should:

1. Create a build folder.
2. `cd` into the build folder.
3. `qmake /path/to/sources/project.pro && make -j`

That's how you distribute and build Qt projects.

> why does qmake not build the application directly?

Why do you not make your own shoes? The reasons are the same. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Of course, engineers sometimes have an itch to scratch. Enter [Qt Build System (qbs)](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/). If your project's build is given as a `.qbs` file, then you do:

1. Create a build root folder.
2. `cd` into the build root folder.
3. `qbs -f /path/to/sources/project.qbs` - this builds the project.